# Copying matrix from .txt into array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a task to read matrix from .txt file and then make an 2D array in C. I read numbers well but I have a problem with writing these numbers into array because I need to allocate memory because im not sure how big the matrix will be.

```
int read()
{

   FILE *f;
   int number, i, j, size;

   f = fopen("matrix.txt","r");
   if (f == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error reading matrix.txt\n");
      return 1;
   }

   printf("Sucess! \n");
   fscanf(f, "%d",&size);
   printf("Size of matrix: %d\n", size,size);

   int* matrix;

   matrix = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

   for(; feof(f) == 0;)
   {
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
              fscanf(f,"%i",&number);
//          *(*(matrix+j)+i) = number; 
              printf("%i\t",number);
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
   }
   fclose(f);
```

Comment: is there more than one matrix in the file ?

Comment: no, only one. but I have this error invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')| in // line ; i have no idea how to write these numbers into array

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, `matrix` is of type `int*` and you intend to store `size*size` elements read from the file into it. First of all, you should allocate memory for `size*size` times the size of `int`, which can be done as follows.

```
matrix = malloc(size * size * sizeof(int));
```

Next, as you iterate via `i` and `j` over the matrix entries which are read from the file, you need to do a proper address calculation. As `matrix` is of type `int*`, this can be done as follows.

```
matrix[ i * ( size - 1 ) + j ] = number;
```

That being said, perhaps it would be better to have `matrix` of type `int**` and allocate space for the rows manually. By doing so, you could do the access to the elements by

```
matrix[ i ][ j ] = number;
```

which is perhaps more intuitive.

Comment: but the second way has the overhead of indirect memory access

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
matrix[(size-1)*i+j]=number
```

To fill the array, that is the usual way to simulate 2D arrays in C, to understand from where did `(size-1)*i+j` come from notice this example :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

the result array is : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

So when we begin in the first row and first column, in the result array 1 is the first element so its index is zero.

When we advance one row(from 1 to 4) we advance three positions in the result array so the index is 3.

Now if we begin with column 1(second column) and the first row we have 2 which has index 1 in the result array, if we advance one row(from 2 to 5) we also advance 3 positions and the index is 4.

Notice that 3 is actually the size of matrix and I think you can verify that `i*(size-1)+j` is working, the `size-1` is like this because C arrays are zero-based.

### Note

If your file only has one matrix, I recommend you to get rid of the outermost loop , a simple mistake(like a new line after the matrix or space) will cause a call to `fscanf(f,"%i",&number)` without finding a number(I'm not sure what will happen then).

Also you should allocate `size*size` of ints.